# Transformations on a piece of paper

Tags: geometry, conformal-geometry

Consider that I have a piece of paper, and I do a drawing on such paper. Now, consider the set of all possible "transformations" I can apply to this piece of paper that do not tear it. For example, I can rotate it, I can do an origami, I can make it into a cylinder... Is there a name for the set of all of such transformations?

Could I say that all these transformations are within the conformal transformations, i.e. since conformal transformations also have scaling, could I say that the set of such transformations that do not tear the paper are within the set of conformal transformations?

Comment: Is it allwoed sticking? (For example, making a cylinder and use glue to stick the borders), If it isn't, I think you mean 'isotopies'

Comment: Folding and bending doesn't preserve angles, so I wouldn't call them conformal.

Comment: I'd think "almost-everywhere local isometry" is closer.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews If you mark two different points $X$ and $Y$ on the paper, $d(X,Y)=\epsilon>0$. And if the paper is bent along their bisector, $d(X',Y')=0$. I'd not say that this is an isometry, local or non local. If the keyword is 'almos-everywhere', mark disjoint, congruent disks instead of points.

Comment: @ajotatxe That was why I said "local isometry" and "almost everywhere." It is definitely not an isometry. All we can say is that at *most* points, there is a neighborhood where the map is an isometry. Even then, you can't use the definition of distance in the co-domain, but rather must use a "shortest path" definition in the range. So, for almost all $x,$ there is an open set $U$ containing $x$ such that, for each $y,z\in U,$ the shortest path length between $f(y)$ and $f(z)$ is $d(y,z).$

Comment: Sticking not allowed... How does folding alter the "angle" of the drawing?

Comment: Interesting concept! It seems "conformal"( + sharp folds) as these locally preserve the angle and area in nice ways, further in a very rigid way (no stretching, since it is paper plus additional structure on the boundary). Guessing it doesn't have a name... *papermorphisms* could be a good name? I know that maps of polygons/linkages have been studied and their moduli space of embedding, seems like a similar feeling (although simpler) concept. I imagine the folds would correspond to singularities if you were to consider the moduli space of such maps (up to equivlance in $\mathbb R^3$)

Comment: or *origamimorphism*, although there is already something called an orgami but sometimes names clash but I don't think there is something called an origamimorphism. Or even just call it a *origami map*

Comment: The idea here is that a drawing in a piece is preserved even after all sort of weird things one does to the papers, as long as you don't rip it or glue stuff. Hence, these transformations always have an inverse (unfolding the paper). I don't know what a "sharp fold" is mathematically.

Comment: Wild guess. Would sharp folds perhaps be the limit of some sequence of conformal transformations? Perhaps closing the set under such things would give me what I'm looking for?